# Differentiating the composition of a scalar and a vector field using the chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, vector-fields, scalar-fields

I have a vector $V=[v_0,v_1...v_n]'$  which is a function of another Vector $W=[w_0,w_1,...,w_n]'$. Here $'$ denotes the transpose.

The scalar field is $f=V'(W) V(W)$  where $V$ and $W$ are of the same dimension $(n+1), n=0,1,...,n$.

I need the gradient. So I think this is the chain rule and I need the Jacobian matrix - is this right?

$$del(f) = 2JV$$

where $J$ is the Jacobion representing the differentiation of the vector $V$ wrt the vector $W$.

Also I am confused about the form of the Jacobian. Standard form has each row as follows eg. row $0$ would be

$$[dv_0/dw_0, \, dv_0/dv_1, \, \cdots, \, dv_0/dv_n]$$

Now to prove this I set up a summation $$f=\sum_{i=0}^n v(w_0,w_1,...,w_n)(i)^2 $$

$$ \frac{df}{v(i)} = 2\sum_{i=0}^n v\cdot \frac{dv(j)}{di}, \quad   j=0,1,...,n$$

Does this look right? - sorry the text may put my equation off skew

Answer (score 0):

Let scalar field $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$$f (x) = \mathrm{v}^T (x) \, \mathrm{v} (x)$$

where $\mathrm{v} : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a given vector field. Taking the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x_k$,

$$\partial_k f (x) = \partial_k \left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \mathrm{v}_i^2 (x) \right) = 2 \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \mathrm{v}_i (x) \, \partial_k \mathrm{v}_i (x) = 2 \langle \partial_k \mathrm{v} (x), \mathrm{v} (x)\rangle$$

Hence, the gradient of $f$ is

$$\nabla f (x) = 2 \begin{bmatrix} | & | & & |\\ \partial_1 \mathrm{v} (x) & \partial_2 \mathrm{v} (x) & \dots & \partial_n \mathrm{v} (x)\\  | & | & & |\end{bmatrix}^T \mathrm{v} (x)$$

where the matrix of partial derivatives above is the transpose of the Jacobian matrix of $\mathrm{v}$.